# Plotting a partial sum

Tags: special-functions, summation

I am given the Legendre expansion of the first kind.
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}P_{n}(x).$$

I have worked the coefficient to be 
$$A_{n}=\frac{1}{\left \| P_{n}(x) \right \|^{2}} \int_{x=-1}^{x=1}f(x)P_{n}dx
$$

Here are my codes:
[image]

The function f is also given. I'm trying to sum the expression as outlined. How should I go about implementing some kind of loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your book refers to the norm of the Legendre polynomials it is using the $L^2$ norm, because the orthogonality relationship is

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x) P_n(x)  dx = \frac{2}{(2 m+1)}  \delta_{mn} $$

So,

```
f[x_] := x^3 - 4 x^2 + 4 x + 2
a[m_, f_] := a[m, f] = (2 m + 1)/2 Integrate[LegendreP[m, x] f[x], {x, -1, 1}]

Manipulate[
 k = Sum[a[m, f] LegendreP[m, #], {m, 0, i}] &;
 Plot[{k[t], f[t]}, {t, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> "Order: " <> ToString@i],
 {i, 0, 5, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example:

```
f[x_] := UnitStep[x]
a[m_, f_] := a[m, f] = (2 m + 1)/2 Integrate[LegendreP[m, x] f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
k = Sum[a[m, f] LegendreP[m, #], {m, 0, i}] &;
Plot[Evaluate@Join[{f[t]}, Table[k[t], {i, 1, 9, 2}]], {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why is there a # within the square bracket of the Legendre algorithm?
Dummy variable?

Comment: @Physkid It's paired with the  `&` at the end, forming a function/argument pair. See for example [**this answer**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193), and all the other answers in that question too, BTW.

Comment: @Physkid It's more or less  equivalent to `k = Function[{s}, Sum[a[m, f] LegendreP[m, s], {m, 0, i}]]`

Comment: In particular, readers ought to notice the Gibbs ringing in the second picture…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.I remember learning about it while reading a Michelson biography as a child. I was mesmerized :)

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot! 
And yes, I do notice the gibbs phenomenon. That's an indication of discontinuities.